# Error when call write()

Tags: android, jexcelapi

I have error in line:

```
    workbook.write();
```

When I try debug, i see massage: "Source not found."

How it fix?

```
    private void exportExcel() throws IOException, WriteException{

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/backup.xls");

    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);
    workbook.createSheet("worksheet", 0);

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

---

WTF my code above begin to work!!!

When I started, I using [default jexcelapi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/). Afterwards I begin using [alternative jexcelapi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelandroid/), but it also not work.

When I try your code with little changes - it work! Your code:

```
    private void exportExcel() throws WriteException, IOException{

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard + "/myFolder");

    //make them in case they're not there
    dir.mkdirs();

    //create a standard java.io.File object for the Workbook to use
    File wbfile = new File(dir, "backup.xls");

    WritableWorkbook workbook = null;

    try{
      workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile);
      workbook.createSheet("worksheet", 0);

      workbook.write();
      workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("Workbook Test", "Could not create " + wbfile.getPath(), ex);
    }
}
```

But when I try my code above, it also work.

**Maybe Eclipse not instantly update using library?**

Thank you very much!

P.S. Excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: I can't say what is the error, but i know this is IOException.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for answer! I create "myFolder" on root folder in SD card and change code, but error remain. Trouble like me: http://anddev.org/general-f3/jexcel-api-ouput-to-sdcard-t16212.html I can use CSV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not check that the external storage directory is actually available. You need to call [`getExternalStorageState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) and check the return value against the various `MEDIA_*` values defined in `Environment`. If the directory is not available, that may cause the problem.

The problem also may be that you are trying to write to the root of the external storage directory. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29):

> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDir`, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled.

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard + "/myFolder");

//make them in case they're not there
dir.mkdirs();

//create a standard java.io.File object for the Workbook to use
File wbfile = new File(dir, "backup.xls");

try{
  WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile);
  workbook.createSheet("worksheet", 0);

  workbook.write();
  workbook.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Log.e("Workbook Test", "Could not create " + wbfile.getPath(), ex);
}
return wb;
```

That should tell you more about what's going on.

**EDIT 2**

After a little more research, I found another possible issue: JExcelApi uses a lot of resources when it is creating a file. One solution is to use a temp file. Add the following code:

```
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
```

and inside the `try` block, change the line that creates the workbook:

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile, wbSettings);
```